# OperationContext.Current in event : Null exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to call a callbackcontract method in a method, which is called when a certain event is triggered. But i get an exception when tried to get the OperationContext.Current. How can I call the callback method only when this event is triggered.

```
private void recordInserted()  //This method is called when the event is fired
{
 ICallbackContract callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbackContract>();
 callback.insertsuccessful();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your `recordInserted` method called from? Server side? if so, you can't magically send something to your client in this fashion.

When the client first connects you need to store a *reference* to the callback and then when your event is fired you use this to send the data back to the client.

eg

```
public class Service
{
     ICallbackContract _callback
     public void Login()
     {
             //method your connecting client calls
         _callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbackContract>();

     }
     private void recordInserted()  //This method is called when the event is fired
     {

          _callback.insertsuccessful();
     }
}
```

It would also make it easier to explain if you post your WCF contract specifications

Comment: _Where is your recordInserted method called from? Server side?_ Yes, its from server side. I got your point. Silly mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: post your wcf contract specifications. or explain how your client connects to the server initially. you can't just call a method that originates on the server and have it push data back to the client; that server thread knows nothing about the client (hence `OperationContext.Current` is null)